# Stop solution wide analysis when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2022

When I open a solution in Visual Studio, resharper performs a solution-wide analysis degrading the performance for up to a minute.

However, I have disabled solution-wide analysis in the settings.

[image]

If I right click the icon in the bottom right corner, I am able to turn the analysis off, and that seems to not affect my work. I do not lose any functionality doing that.

The next time I open the solution, the solution wide analysis will start again.

Is there a way to turn it off without right clicking every time I open a solution? What is "Enable code analysis?"

Comment: I wonder if its Visual Studio's built in analysis tools? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzly7.png

Comment: Works for me with R# `2022.2.3` and VS 2022 `17.3.4` - maybe a bug in an older version?